# Convert cell to double

Tags: matlab, double, cell-array

```
>> C = [{1} {2} ; {'@CF'} {2}] 
C = 

[  1]    [2]
'@CF'    [2]


>> whos C
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes

  C         2x2               478  cell
```

How can I convert `C` into `double` so that:

```
>> C
C = 
1    2
NaN  2
```

I've tried `str2double(C)`.  It returns:

```
   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Find the non numeric values with [isnumeric](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/isnumeric.html), queried by [cellfun](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/cellfun.html). Use that with [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.nl/company/newsletters/articles/Matrix-Indexing-in-MATLAB/matrix.html) to extract the numeric values:

```
C = [{1} {2} ; {'@CF'} {2}];
isnum = cellfun(@isnumeric,C);
result = NaN(size(C));
result(isnum) = [C{isnum}];
```

Comment: A shorter way to code is, C(cellfun(@ischar, C) = {NaN};
C = cell2mat(C);

Comment: @user1532230: No, it's quite the same. I even suspect `cell2mat` takes more time than my simple array writing and reading code.

Answer (score 12):

```
C = [{1} {2} ; {'@CF'} {2}]

C = 

    [  1]    [2]
    '@CF'    [2]

D = cellfun(@isnumeric,C);
C(~D)={nan}

C = 

    [  1]    [2]
    [NaN]    [2]

cell2mat(C)

ans =

     1     2
   NaN     2
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have mixed data types here so there isn't a very straight forward way to do it.

The easiest way I can think of, if you know where the data is you want, is to simply use `cell2mat`

IE: `cell2mat(C(1,1))` would return 1 as a double.