# Convert cell array of strings to double array

Tags: matlab

I have a cell in Matlab that looks like this:

```
'1406200719565'
'1406200719583'
'1406200719598'
'1406200730211'
'1406200730226'
'1406200730242'
'1406200731023'
'1406200731889'
'1406200732801'
'1406200733670'
```

I want no to convert each of this String into a double and then into a double array. I followed various approaches I could find in the net, but none of them worked. E.g. I used the approach recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525996/convert-cell-to-double), but the result is just a vector with NaNs. What else can I do?

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried this:

```
S={'1406200719565'
   '1406200719583'
   '1406200719598'
   '1406200730211'
   '1406200730226'
   '1406200730242'
   '1406200731023'
   '1406200731889'
   '1406200732801'
   '1406200733670'}

cellfun(@str2num, S)
```

Comment: or just `str2double(S)`

Answer (score 1):

It appears there is no reason to use cellfun. str2double is already vectorized and works with cells. However, when comparing performance cellfun is actually significantly (i.e. measurable) faster!

```
S={'1406200719565'
   '1406200719583'
   '1406200719598'
   '1406200730211'
   '1406200730226'
   '1406200730242'
   '1406200731023'
   '1406200731889'
   '1406200732801'
   '1406200733670'}

X = zeros(10,1);

tic
for ii = 1:20000
X=str2double(S);
end
toc
```

Output: Elapsed time is 3.908324 seconds.

```
tic
for ii = 1:20000
X = cellfun(@str2double, S);
end
toc
```

Output: Elapsed time is 3.357150 seconds.

As suggested by @Divakar a comparison using a larger cell array emphasizing the gain in performance by using cullfun:

```
S=cellstr(num2str(randi(150000,10000,1)));
X = zeros(150000,10000);
tic
X=str2double(S);
toc
tic
X = cellfun(@str2double, S);
toc
```

Resulting in:

**Direct**: Elapsed time is **0.778316 seconds**.

Using **cellfun**: Elapsed time is **0.173727 seconds**.

**Note**
Virtually no difference in using str2num or str2double. str2num seems 3% slower, but is not significantly.

Comment: I think a fair comparison would be when you increase the datasize, something like - `S = cellstr(num2str(randi(1000000,100000,1)))`.

Comment: Cellfun shows a significant increase in performance

Comment: +1 for the comparisons, but can you add my solution into your time test please? i.e. `str2num` instead of `str2double`?